# jQuery push values from unlimited ul levels to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to push all `ul>li` values from unlimited childrens (eg ul>ul>ul>ul..) in JSON.

So I did this but I can't loop the `Subcategories`

```
getCategories(elem){
   $(elem).children().each(function() {
       var el = $(this),
           child = $(this).children('ul'),
           item = {
              Id: el.data('id'),
              URL: el.find('a').attr('href'),
              Name: el.find('a').text(),
              Sort: el.data('sort'),
              if (child.length > 0) {
                 Subcategories: getCategories(child);
              }
           };
           categories.push(item);
      });
      return categories
}
item['categories'] = getCategories('#categories ul.ui-sortable');
```

and sample HTML:

```
<div id="categories">
    <ul class="ui-sortable">
        <li><a>1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>1.1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>1.1.1</a>
                        ....
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Right now I am getting only first levels and tried a function/loop with no luck.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

**UPDATE:** [**This is a fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wzvte794/) of what I did untill now, but still wrong, subcategories = 2x

Comment: ul has a tree-structure. it's simple to iterate with a dfs-alogrithm

Answer (score 0):

Don't write like this : $(elem).children().each(function() {

instead of this code , try:

```
 $(elem).find("ul").each(function() {
});
```

This selector will be run for all **ul** under that element

Comment: His function is recursive, find get all nested ul elements

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for *help* I fixed it

```
function pushULtoJson(elem){
        var array = []
        $(elem).first().children('li').each(function(i){
            var Subcategories = []
            var childUL = $(this).find('>ul');
            array.push({
                Id: $(this).data('id'),
                URL: $(this).find('a').attr('href'),
                Name: $(this).find('>a').text().replace(/'/g,"’"),
                Subcategories:pushULtoJson(childUL)
            });
        });
        return array
    }
```